# SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 Binary deployment error message is not descriptive

Tags: 2013-sp1

In SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 when you try to publish two distinct multimedia components to pubish to the same location, then Tridion will refuse to deploy the second item. Instead, you’ll get some cryptic message like:
"Committing Deployment Failed Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed.Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4445-66560"

You have to dig deeper in the deployer log to find the actual error which is like this 
"2015-01-07 15:02:25,088 WARN PreCommitPhase - Failed to Prepare: tcm:0-4445-66560 error:Attempting to deploy a binary 8029 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 8030:

Is there any configuration in SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 which can be switched on, so that the detailed error is visible in the transaction work flow when you click on the "failed" button ?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a problem with 2013 SP1, and I wrote about it in my blog article about [publishing binary assets](https://blog.indivirtual.nl/publishing-binary-assets-sdl-tridion/). At the time of writing that article, I discussed the issue with Tridion insiders who informed me that this is a known issue and it is regarded as a bug. The expectation therefore is that it will be fixed in a forthcoming version.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed errors for deployers are visible in logs only. so you have to check it there. you can simply search [ERROR] in the log file to find any errors.

also regrading your error. because two different component using same binary and published with the same name which is not allowed. you can choose append tcmid of parent component on each multimedia item to avoid such issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hotfix for this - CD_2013.1.0.88163.  Available [here](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx) (login required). It brings back the more detailed error message from previous versions.